# How to get pointer address in function that called through this pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I read [this article](https://gnu.huihoo.org/gcc/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return%20Address) but it doesn't answer my question.

**file: hero.h**

```c
typedef struct {
    int     id;
    void    (*setId)();
    int     (*getId)();
} Hero, *HeroPtr;
```

**file: hero.c**

```c
#include "hero.h"

static void setId(int id);

Hero obj = {
     .setId = setId,
     .getId = getId,
};

void setId(int id) {
    HeroPtr hero_obj = 0x0; //TODO how get address: hero_obj1 (1 > ) OR 
                            //                      hero_obj2 (2 > )
    hero_obj->id = id;
}

void getId() {
    HeroPtr hero_obj = 0x0; //TODO how get address: hero_obj1 (1 > ) OR 
                            //                      hero_obj2 (2 > )
    return hero_obj->id;
}
```

**file: main.c**

```c
#include "hero.h"

int main() {
    Hero hero_obj1, hero_obj2;
//1 >
    hero_obj1->setId(1);
//2 >
    hero_obj2->setId(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem better. Does it compile? If no, what error? If yes, how does the code not work as it should?

Comment: I guess you are looking for c++

Comment: @OznOg :) no, I need use only "C"

Comment: IMHO, what I understand you are trying to do is not feasible. How would the function know about it to be called thru a pointer held in a structure?
Usually in C, when you mock object oriented programming, you pass the "object" expllicitly to the function, thus would be `setId(Hero *, int id)`.

Comment: Moreover, what would be supposed to happen if there is no Hero in the first place when calling the function? (save the pointer and call it from nowhere)

Comment: @OznOg I agree with you, but your option is not appropriate for me, you may be able to get addresses using assembler inserts, or understand how it is implemented in C ++

Comment: well, in C++, the object is passed :); any trick by assembly or compiler is not C anyway.

Comment: I simplified the code so that only the essence of the question can be seen

Comment: The answer hasn't changed: You need to pass it yourself. There is no trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement virtual functions in C, by using function pointers. In object-oriented programming languages like C++ or Java such functions or methods inside classes have an implicit `this` pointer as argument, which is hidden. That means that the `int getId()` function actually has the signature `int getId(Hero* this)` and the `void setId(int id)` function actually has the form `void setId(Hero* this, int id)`. As I have already said, in object-oriented programming languages you don't see or add the `this` pointer and you also don't pass the argument when you invoke the function. The compiler does this for you. It always automatically passes the pointer to the instance as `this` pointer, on which the function was invoked. In C, however, these features don't exist. So you have to add the `this` argument and pass it when invoking the function by yourself.

Comment: and this is particularly visible when writing a lambda that needs to call a member function, `this` needs to be captured. If the guess from the pointer was possible, capturing `this` wouldn't be needed

Answer (score 0):

You could do the equivalent of what C++ does behind the scenes.

**file: hero.h**

```
typedef struct hero {
    int     id;
    void    (*setId)(struct hero*, int);
    int     (*getId)(struct hero*);
} Hero, *HeroPtr;

void constructHero(HeroPtr this);
```

**file: hero.c**

```
#include "hero.h"                                       
static void setId(HeroPtr this, int id);                
static int getId(HeroPtr this);                         

Hero initObj = {                                        
 .setId = &setId,                                   
 .getId = &getId,                                   
};                                                      

void constructHero(HeroPtr this)                        
{                                                       
    *this = initObj;                                
}                                                       

void setId(HeroPtr this, int id) {                      
    HeroPtr hero_obj = this;                            
    hero_obj->id = id;                              
}                                                       

int getId(HeroPtr this) {                               
    HeroPtr hero_obj = this;                            

    return hero_obj->id;                                
}
```

**file: main.c**

```
#include "hero.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    Hero hero1;
    Hero hero2;
    HeroPtr hero_obj1=&hero1;
    HeroPtr hero_obj2=&hero2;
    constructHero(hero_obj1);
    constructHero(hero_obj2);
    hero_obj1->setId(hero_obj1, 1);
    hero_obj2->setId(hero_obj2, 2);
    printf("hero_obj1 id = %d\n", hero_obj1->getId(hero_obj1));
    printf("hero_obj2 id = %d\n", hero_obj2->getId(hero_obj2));

    return 0;
}
```